# Async callback timeout when unit testing nested async function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to implement a function which hits some apis asynchronously and does some calculations. However I would like to use promises (also because I thought its easy to write unit test for them)

This is the function I want to write.

```
const CalcFactory = (someApi1, someApi2, someApi3) => 
 async function calculation(params){
  return new Promise((res, rej) =>{
    const data1 = someApi1.getData() // getData is async
    someApi2.getData((err, data) =>{
       if(err)
         rej(err);
       else
         res();
      });
    });
 }
```

The question now is how to test and mock this? My first test is if all the api methods are beeing called but I already struggle with that.

```
const Calculator = CalcFactory(api1Mock, api2Mock, api3Mock);

if('should hit all external apis', () => {
return Calculator(somedada).then(()=>{
   expect(api1Mock.getData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(someData);
   expect(api2Mock.getData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(somedata);
   });

});
```

the mocks look like this:

```
const api1Mock = {
   someData: jest.fn(),
}

const api2Mock = {
someData: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      data:{},
   })
}
```

However I always get a timeout when I run the test. I am also not really sure if this is a good approach to write the function but I really would like to use a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `getData` in one place and `someData` in another. Considering the promise is not rejected, it's not a problem. `Calculator(somedada)` promise isn't resolved because `someApi2.getData` is incorrectly mocked and results in pending promise.

It's an antipattern to return a promise from `async` function without using `await`. This means that either it doesn't benefit from being `async`, or promise constructor contains too much besides promisfication of non-promise API.

In case the use of `async` is justified, it can be:

```
async function calculation(params){
  ...
  const data1 = someApi1.getData()
  const data2 = await new Promise((res, rej) =>{
      someApi2.getData((err, data) => {
       if(err)
         rej(err);
       else
         res();
      });
  });
  ...
}
```

In Node, error-first callbacks can be promisified with `util.promisify`.

And mocked `someApi2.getData` should use a callback like expected:

```
const api2Mock = {
  getData: jest.fn().mockImplementation(cb => cb(null, 'data'))
}
```

If `someApi2.getData` is used more than once, it makes sense to promisify it instead of using promise constructor every time.

Comment: thank, I promisified `someApi2.getData` and just await the promise which works fine.